# Display configurable product's price and options several times on the same page?

Tags: configurable-product

Is there a native (strong and simple as a bonus) way to repeat the product prices and options (like sizes, colors, etc.) display on the same page ?

Same question shorter (but maybe there is an other way ?) : can I display both "container1" and "container2" blocks on the same page ?

I tried to echo several times the wanted blocks, but I'm experimenting js conflicts because of duplicate input ids : only the last drop-down list (of each option) is functional, others are empty...

I also tried to use both "container1" and "container2" blocks (removing the unsetCallChild calls in layout) but problem is the same : container1's option drop-down lists are populated, but not container2's lists.

Comment: Have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4499/766 which explains a bit of related background.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no easy way :(

I ran into the same issue when I enhanced my Gifts module[1] to the ability to gift configurables, and display them as selectable items in the cart.

I had to extend the core product.js object to allow passing of a unique id (which I assign to each product as a value using php's uniqueid[2] command.

This then allowed each configurable's dropdowns to be unique and not clash.

Here is my ext-product.js

```
Object.extend(Product.Config.prototype, {
       initialize: function(config,uniqueid){
        this.config     = config;
        this.taxConfig  = this.config.taxConfig;
        this.settings   = $$('.super-attribute-select-'+uniqueid);
        this.state      = new Hash();
        this.priceTemplate = new Template(this.config.template);
        this.prices     = config.prices;

        this.settings.each(function(element){
            Event.observe(element, 'change', this.configure.bind(this))
        }.bind(this));

        // fill state
        this.settings.each(function(element){
            var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, '');
            if(attributeId && this.config.attributes[attributeId]) {
                element.config = this.config.attributes[attributeId];
                element.attributeId = attributeId;
                this.state[attributeId] = false;
            }
        }.bind(this))

        // Init settings dropdown
        var childSettings = [];
        for(var i=this.settings.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            var prevSetting = this.settings[i-1] ? this.settings[i-1] : false;
            var nextSetting = this.settings[i+1] ? this.settings[i+1] : false;
            if(i==0){
                this.fillSelect(this.settings[i])
            }
            else {
                this.settings[i].disabled=true;
            }
            $(this.settings[i]).childSettings = childSettings.clone();
            $(this.settings[i]).prevSetting   = prevSetting;
            $(this.settings[i]).nextSetting   = nextSetting;
            childSettings.push(this.settings[i]);
        }

        // Set default values - from config and overwrite them by url values
        if (config.defaultValues) {
            this.values = config.defaultValues;
        }

        var separatorIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('#');
        if (separatorIndex != -1) {
            var paramsStr = window.location.href.substr(separatorIndex+1);
            var urlValues = paramsStr.toQueryParams();
            if (!this.values) {
                this.values = {};
            }
            for (var i in urlValues) {
                this.values[i] = urlValues[i];
            }
        }

        this.configureForValues();
        document.observe("dom:loaded", this.configureForValues.bind(this));
    }
});
```

and in the templates I output the unique id for the generation of the dropdown templates.

It was not a simple task and took a few days, and is spread over a few template and layout files. If I get time this weekend, I will try and explain all I did.

[1] [Gift module](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/magento-modules/magento-gift-promotions.html)

[2] [php uniqueid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

as an example of the adjustment [demo product showing multiple configurables dropdowns](http://giftpromodemo.proxiblue.com.au/htc-touch-diamond.html) and add to cart

Yes, not exactly the same as you want, but the principle is the same. (I am using core blocks via layout in the cart)